# Making short url for doctor profile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting

I have made website using JSF 2.0 and MySQL.

I have one page where I am showing doctor profile:

```
http://www.example.com/faces/doctorProfile.xhtml?profileName=drrajesh
```

What my client is asking is one of the following:

```
http://www.example.com/drrajesh
http://www.example.com/faces/drrajesh
```

They want it like Facebook/instagram.

Any idea how this can be done in JSF?

**Note: I want this for this specific page only and not for whole website.**

Even if I get url as below is fine with me.

```
htttp://wwww.mywebsite.com/doctorprofile/drrajesh
```

---

### Edit 1

While research I found below link

http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

but I am not sure how can I use in my case.

This is useful for static url change, but in my case it is different. My url is dynamic.

Comment: What research have you done / things have you tried so far?

Comment: @snickers10m : check my updated question for the same...

Comment: Research that you've done that does not solve your problem is just as useful as research that has, because it allows us to focus the issue and may introduce constraints that were not obvious before. Hence why we ask for research.

Comment: Thank you for updating, I can now upvote with confidence. :)

Comment: @snickers10m : Check [this](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). Will this help me? I think it would be help a lot... will investigate more tomorrow... now sleeping time... i am yawning to much... Zzzzz....

Comment: @snickers10m : Or I think [this is best](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1062/write-your-own-url-rewrite-filter-for-existing-jsf-pages)

Comment: PrettyFaces is not for static url's only on the contrary. It can populate params dynamically based on parts of the (dynamic) url