# Removing /faces/ from URL in JSF applications

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting

I have made website using JSF 2.0

All links goes as below.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/faces/index.xhtml
```

What I want is remove /faces/, so that final url would be as below.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.xhtml
```

Note: I want to achieve this while passing parameters.

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449660/making-short-url-for-doctor-profile)

What I tried is changing filter criteria for my new filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.lab.filter.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**TO**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.lab.filter.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> // here made change from /* to /
</filter-mapping>
```

But it was giving errors. No web page is showing.

What I want to achieve from previous is mywebsite.com/faces/dr.rajesh to mywebsite.com/dr.rajesh

---

Full WEB-INF as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.lab.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.lab.filter.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewrite</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far!  (What you did following your last question).

Comment: You should have mapped `FacesServlet` that way. How does the URL pattern of `FacesServlet` look like? It should look something like `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`. (You can give it any suffix of your interest other than `xhtml` given that you will need to protect XHTML pages from being directly accessed from the browser, if you use other than the `xhtml` suffix).

Comment: @Tiny : <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> is already there in web-inf

Comment: Where is it? `FacesServlet` is mapped to the pattern `/faces/*`. Look closely.

Comment: @Tiny : I got **SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [www.abc.com]
SEVERE: Invalid URL Pattern: [*xhtml]**

Comment: Type carefully. Read the exception message what it says, `*xhtml` is an invalid/incorrect URL pattern. You need this instead `*.xhtml` - in combination with a star (asterisk), a dot and xhtml in the same order in which they appear here. You missed a dot.

Comment: Don't forget to modify the welcome page entry to remove the /faces part of the destination.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your web.xml you **just** need the url pattern below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and remove the other mapping to the Faces Servlet.

In modern JSF versions (>2.1), you don't need any entries in the web.xml at all since the are present 'on' the Faces Servlet via annotations and will be parsed.

Comment: How does your web.xml look like?

Comment: That should do it - try.

Comment: I got **SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [www.abc.com] : Invalid URL Pattern: [*xhtml]**

Comment: @user3728970 : Type carefully. Read the exception message what it says, `*xhtml` is an invalid/incorrect URL pattern. You need this instead `*.xhtml` - in combination with a star (asterisk), dot and xhtml in the same order in which they appear here. You missed a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below content from  WEB-INF web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```